# Django - Migrations mixed up?

Tags: python, django, migration

I've been working on a contract project in Django, and I performed some updates for the live server, including updates that went from South to an up to date Django version.

I was attempting to follow the instructions in the documentation, which states to delete all the old migration files except **init**, and then use makemigrations and "python manage.py migrate --fake-initial".

But it turns out database permissions were screwy. I was not able to apply the update.

The server owner (who was the past contractor) did not yet realize that there was a permission issue, and tried the update on his own.

The server is now working, but he stated to me he "**had to do many changes to the migrations working because there was no old migrations**".

**I am assuming he did not know the proper way to upgrade from South to integration migrations with Django, and did it all manually rather than letting Django migrations do the work**.

Well now I am ready for future updates, but I look in the migrations folder, and it looks like both the old migrations files as well as the new migrations files are in there? An example: http://screencast.com/t/gYQdc1tl4 (notice the dates).

Everything seems to be working, but I am wondering... how should I go about future migrations from here? Will a regular makemigrations/migrate work? Or should I do the --fake-initial again?

Any suggestions please? Since we strayed from documentation I'm unsure of how to go about this next.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything works now and you don't need the migrations for your development server, then I would just remove all old migrations (do a backup!) and start with "new migrations" using `--fake-initial`

Comment: Worked fine, thank you! One other question though... For when I deploy this from the development server to the live server. Would there be any issues if I migrated the development server then copied over the migrated database along with the files? Or would it only work properly if I run the migrations on the live server? Would the only issue be making sure the database is up to date?